# In Spring JPARepository, how do I select distinct column values rather than distinct entities?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, db2

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5 and JPA 2.1.  I have the following entity, mapped to a DB2 table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="XYZVVV00")
public class MyProduct {
   ...
   @Column(nullable=false)
   private String prodType;

}
```

and I have the following repository ...

```
public interface MyProductRepository extends JpaRepository<MyProduct, Long> {
    ...
    @Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT PROD_TYPE FROM XYZVVV00", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<String> findDistinctProdTypes();

}
```

Is there a way to write my Spring code without having to use a native query?

Comment: Just for clarification. Are you looking to find a way to write queries without nativeQuery (aka standard SQL)? Or to find a way to not select all the entity's columns and select only certain columns? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

TO get all `DISTINCT` values FROM a entity without using native query you can write something like this:

```
  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT product.prodType FROM MyProduct product")
  List<String> findAllDistinctProductType();
```

It is going to return an result based on your entity that you also provide

Comment: This results in the error upon application startup, "No property findDistinctByProductType found for type MyProduct!"

Comment: instead of writing `ProductType` write there column of your entity , I wrote so as an example. In your case `ProdType`

Comment: i made an update to the answer, can you check now ?

Comment: Thanks for your update but this results in the same error.

Comment: i did a change to the answer , can you check now, based on your entity it is going to work well. My bad was first answer)